# Alternative area of a triangle formula

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, area

The problem is as follows:
There is a triangle $ABC$ and I need to show that it's area is: $$\frac{1}{2} c^2 \frac{\sin A \sin B}{\sin (A+B)}$$
Since there is a half in front I decided that base*height is equivalent to $c^2 \frac{\sin A \sin B}{\sin (A+B)}$. So I made an assumption that base is $c$ and went on to prove that height is $c \frac{\sin A \sin B}{\sin (A+B)}$. But I end up expressing height in terms of itself.. i.e.  $h \equiv \frac{ch}{a\cos B + b \cos A}$. How do I prove this alternative area of triangle formula?

Comment: Oh... I think I showed it. Since $a \cos B + b \cos A \equiv c$ then $ h \equiv h$.... Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's denote by $[ABC]$ the area of $\triangle ABC$, its known that $$[ABC]=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$$
From Sine Law we have  $a\sin C=c\sin A$ and $b\sin C=c\sin B$, also $\sin (A+B)=\sin(\pi-C)=\sin C$, then
\begin{align*}
[ABC]&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(a\sin C)(b\sin C)}{\sin C}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(c\sin A)(c\sin B)}{\sin (A+B)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}c^2\frac{\sin A\sin B}{\sin (A+B)}
\end{align*}

Comment: nice! very neat

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

$$\frac{1}{2}bh \equiv \frac{1}{2}c^2\frac{\sin A \sin B}{\sin (A+B)}$$

Assume that $b$ = $c$.

Then, $c\frac{\sin A \sin B}{\sin (A+B)} \equiv \frac{c}{\cot A + \cot B}$. But $\cot A \equiv \frac{b \cos A}{h}$ and $\cot B \equiv \frac{a\cos B}{h}$. Therefore $\frac{c}{\cot A + \cot B} \equiv \frac{ch}{a\cos B + b\cos A}$. Since $a\cos B + b\cos A \equiv c$, we have $h \equiv \frac{ch}{c}$. $h\equiv h$.

I realised this after I posted the question...

Answer (score 0):

$$\triangle =\dfrac12bc\sin A=\dfrac12(2R\sin B)c\sin A\cdot\dfrac c{2R\sin C}$$

Now $A+B=\pi-C\implies\sin(A+B)=\sin(\pi-C)=?$

Comment: Is $R$ the radius of the incircle?

Comment: yeap, what is it?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal, See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofSines.html

Comment: @Marconius, It's circum radius