# The trigonometrical properties of a triangle

Tags: triangles, area

I want to prove that $$\text{area}=\frac{1}{2}a^2\frac{\sin B\sin C}{\sin(B+C)}$$
Since $a^2$ this must be an isosceles triangle, I wrote $\;\text{area}=\frac{1}{2}a^2\sin x$
 I squared both sides and the cosine became $\sin^2x=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)$ Does it possible to get the part $\frac{\sin B\sin C}{\sin(B+C)}$

Comment: It is unclear what the quantities $B,C$ are in relation to $x$. Could you explain?

Comment: I tried to prove from the formula

Comment: See also: [Alternative area of a triangle formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1394560). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7Da%5E2%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20B%5Csin%20C%7D%7B%5Csin(B%2BC)%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1):

In fact this works for any triangle. The usual area formula is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin{C}$, with the standard labelling of the capital letter as the angle opposite the side with length the small letter. So if we can show that $b = \sin{B}/\sin{(B+C)}$, we're done. But we have
$$ \frac{\sin{A}}{a} = \frac{\sin{B}}{b} $$
from the sine rule, and since $A=\pi-B-C$ and $\sin{(\pi-\theta)}=\sin{\theta}$, we find the required expression for $B$ after rearranging.